# Web Api ModelState validation is ignoring the DisplayAttribute

Tags: validation, asp.net-web-api

Given a model with these data annotations:

```cs
public class Example
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Activity response")]
    public string ActivityResponse { get; set; }
}
```

I would expect the model state error message to be "The Activity response field is required." Instead it is "The ActivityResponse field is required."

Comment: Sounds like we're inconsistent with MVC on this one - feel free to file a bug on here: http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/list/basic

Comment: Thanks Youssef, the bug report can be found at http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/744

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the same problem and I made a workaround for it. 
I know it is not perfect.

For every dataannotation attribute create a new class

```cs
public class RequiredAttribute : System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.RequiredAttribute
{
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        validationContext.DisplayName = ModelMetadataProviders
            .Current
            .GetMetadataForProperty(null, validationContext.ObjectType, validationContext.DisplayName)
            .DisplayName;
        return base.IsValid(value, validationContext);
    }
}



public class StringLengthAttribute : System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.StringLengthAttribute
{
    public StringLengthAttribute(int maximumLength)
        : base(maximumLength)
    { }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
         validationContext.DisplayName = ModelMetadataProviders
             .Current
             .GetMetadataForProperty(null, validationContext.ObjectType, validationContext.DisplayName)
             .DisplayName;
         return base.IsValid(value, validationContext);
    }
}
```

etc....

Answer (score 2):

Hooray! [The codeplex issue](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/744) reports that this bug will be fixed in Web API v5.1 Preview.