# ASP.NET Web Api: Return user friendly names in error response from ActionFilter/ModelState

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I'm using a view model with an ApiController that has Display(Name = "Friendly Name") attributes for each property. I've created a custom `ActionFilterAttribute` to validate the model state and return a bad request when the model is not valid. What I would like to do now is return custom JSON output that includes the user friendly names related to each model's properties. I can think of some hacky ways to do this but what's the preferred way?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:
This will only be fixed in WebApi 5.1.

Have a look here - [Web Api ModelState validation is ignoring the DisplayAttribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14142133/web-api-modelstate-validation-is-ignoring-the-displayattribute)

---

Have a look at the official Microsoft documentation - [ApiController.Validate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/model-validation-in-aspnet-web-api).

You can achieve this by returning the ModelState in your response. e.g.

```
public class MyController : ApiController
    {
        public HttpResponseMessage Post(Product product)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            }
            else
            {
                return request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ModelState);
            }
        }
    }
```

or if you want to do this through your ActionFilterAttribute you can use:

```
public class ValidateModelAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {
            if (actionContext.ModelState.IsValid == false)
            {
                actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateErrorResponse(
                    HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, actionContext.ModelState);
            }
        }
    }
```

This would return JSON like:

> {   "Message": "The request is invalid.",   "ModelState": {
>       "product": [
>         "Required property 'Name' not found in JSON. Path '', line 1, position 17."
>       ],
>       "product.Name": [
>         "The Name field is required."
>       ],
>       "product.Weight": [
>         "The field Weight must be between 0 and 999."
>       ]   } }

Answer (score 0):

In 'ActionFilterAttribute' you can can customize error message according your api requirement

```
public class ValidateModelAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute{
public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
{
    if (actionContext.ModelState.IsValid == false)
    {
        var error = new
        {
            status = false,
            message = "The request is invalid.",
            error = actionContext.ModelState.Values.SelectMany(e => e.Errors.Select(er => er.ErrorMessage))
        };
        actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, error);
    }
}}
```

> {
>   "status": false,
>   "message": "The request is invalid.",
>   "error": [
>     "The First Name field is required.",
>     "The Lname field is required.",
>     "The Ename field is required."
>   ],
>   }